# Error accessing properties in StatefulWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I'm accessing a property-"startingProduct" in a State Class. The variable was defined in A StatefulWidget Class.
But I get "startingProduct is not defined". How do I fix the code?

```dart
final String startingProduct; // `StatefulWidget` class

ProductManager(this.startingProduct); // `StatefulWidget` class

_products.add(widget.startingProduct); // `State` class
```

```
Error: The getter 'startingProduct' isn't defined for the class 'StatefulWidget'.
```

Comment: can you post your full Stateful widget + State code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you most likely forgot to specify the **type** of the `State` class.

You should use the following syntax:

```dart
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> { // in this case `Example` is your StatefulWidget class
```

To be more clear: I mean that you need to specify the optional type argument `T` as your `StatefulWidget` class, e.g. `extends State<Example>` instead of `extends State`.